# Two similar div containers but only one is working

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

So, you can see, I have added the container div twice but there seems to be some issue with the second form. Only the first form seems to work properly when both of them are entirely the same.

Is there something I am missing? I tried making a folder and trying to run it on my machine but I get the same error.

Thank you!

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/SethCalkins/pen/JoXymK) that I have used.

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 *
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {
  "use strict";

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ("classList" in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + " " + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), " ");
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }
})(window);

/**
 * stepsForm.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2014, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
(function(window) {
  "use strict";

  var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd",
      MozTransition: "transitionend",
      OTransition: "oTransitionEnd",
      msTransition: "MSTransitionEnd",
      transition: "transitionend"
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed("transition")],
    support = {
      transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
    };

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function stepsForm(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();
  }

  stepsForm.prototype.options = {
    onSubmit: function() {
      return false;
    }
  };

  stepsForm.prototype._init = function() {
    // current question
    this.current = 0;

    // questions
    this.questions = [].slice.call(
      this.el.querySelectorAll("ol.questions > li")
    );
    // total questions
    this.questionsCount = this.questions.length;
    // show first question
    classie.addClass(this.questions[0], "current");

    // next question control
    this.ctrlNext = this.el.querySelector("button.next");

    // progress bar
    this.progress = this.el.querySelector("div.progress");

    // question number status
    this.questionStatus = this.el.querySelector("span.number");
    // current question placeholder
    this.currentNum = this.questionStatus.querySelector("span.number-current");
    this.currentNum.innerHTML = Number(this.current + 1);
    // total questions placeholder
    this.totalQuestionNum = this.questionStatus.querySelector(
      "span.number-total"
    );
    this.totalQuestionNum.innerHTML = this.questionsCount;

    // error message
    this.error = this.el.querySelector("span.error-message");

    // init events
    this._initEvents();
  };

  stepsForm.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this,
      // first input
      firstElInput = this.questions[this.current].querySelector("input"),
      // focus
      onFocusStartFn = function() {
        firstElInput.removeEventListener("focus", onFocusStartFn);
        classie.addClass(self.ctrlNext, "show");
      };

    // show the next question control first time the input gets focused
    firstElInput.addEventListener("focus", onFocusStartFn);

    // show next question
    this.ctrlNext.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      self._nextQuestion();
    });

    // pressing enter will jump to next question
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
      var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
      // enter
      if (keyCode === 13) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        self._nextQuestion();
      }
    });

    // disable tab
    this.el.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
      var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
      // tab
      if (keyCode === 9) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  };

  stepsForm.prototype._nextQuestion = function() {
    if (!this._validade()) {
      return false;
    }

    // check if form is filled
    if (this.current === this.questionsCount - 1) {
      this.isFilled = true;
    }

    // clear any previous error messages
    this._clearError();

    // current question
    var currentQuestion = this.questions[this.current];

    // increment current question iterator
    ++this.current;

    // update progress bar
    this._progress();

    if (!this.isFilled) {
      // change the current question number/status
      this._updateQuestionNumber();

      // add class "show-next" to form element (start animations)
      classie.addClass(this.el, "show-next");

      // remove class "current" from current question and add it to the next one
      // current question
      var nextQuestion = this.questions[this.current];
      classie.removeClass(currentQuestion, "current");
      classie.addClass(nextQuestion, "current");
    }

    // after animation ends, remove class "show-next" from form element and change current question placeholder
    var self = this,
      onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.transitions) {
          this.removeEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
        }
        if (self.isFilled) {
          self._submit();
        } else {
          classie.removeClass(self.el, "show-next");
          self.currentNum.innerHTML = self.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML;
          self.questionStatus.removeChild(self.nextQuestionNum);
          // force the focus on the next input
          nextQuestion.querySelector("input").focus();
        }
      };

    if (support.transitions) {
      this.progress.addEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
    } else {
      onEndTransitionFn();
    }
  };

  // updates the progress bar by setting its width
  stepsForm.prototype._progress = function() {
    this.progress.style.width =
      this.current * (100 / this.questionsCount) + "%";
  };

  // changes the current question number
  stepsForm.prototype._updateQuestionNumber = function() {
    // first, create next question number placeholder
    this.nextQuestionNum = document.createElement("span");
    this.nextQuestionNum.className = "number-next";
    this.nextQuestionNum.innerHTML = Number(this.current + 1);
    // insert it in the DOM
    this.questionStatus.appendChild(this.nextQuestionNum);
  };

  // submits the form
  stepsForm.prototype._submit = function() {
    this.options.onSubmit(this.el);
  };

  // TODO (next version..)
  // the validation function
  stepsForm.prototype._validade = function() {
    // current questionВґs input
    var input = this.questions[this.current].querySelector("input").value;
    if (input === "") {
      this._showError("EMPTYSTR");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  // TODO (next version..)
  stepsForm.prototype._showError = function(err) {
    var message = "";
    switch (err) {
      case "EMPTYSTR":
        message = "Please fill the field before continuing";
        break;
      case "INVALIDEMAIL":
        message = "Please fill a valid email address";
        break;
        // ...
    }
    this.error.innerHTML = message;
    classie.addClass(this.error, "show");
  };

  // clears/hides the current error message
  stepsForm.prototype._clearError = function() {
    classie.removeClass(this.error, "show");
  };

  // add to global namespace
  window.stepsForm = stepsForm;
})(window);

var theForm = document.getElementById("theForm");

new stepsForm(theForm, {
  onSubmit: function(form) {
    // hide form
    classie.addClass(theForm.querySelector(".simform-inner"), "hide");

    /*
                    form.submit()
                    or
                    AJAX request (maybe show loading indicator while we don't have an answer..)
                    */

    // let's just simulate something...
    var messageEl = theForm.querySelector(".final-message");
    messageEl.innerHTML = "Thank you! We'll be in touch.";
    classie.addClass(messageEl, "show");
  }
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic);
.simform {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
  max-width: 860px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.simform .submit {
  display: none;
}


/* Question list style */

.simform ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s;
}

.simform ol:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.35em;
}

.questions li {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, height 0s 0.4s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, height 0s 0.4s;
}

.questions li.current,
.no-js .questions li {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}


/* Labels */

.questions li>span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.questions li>span label {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.questions li.current>span label,
.no-js .questions li>span label {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.show-next .questions li.current>span label {
  -webkit-animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
  animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveUpFromDown {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveUpFromDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}


/* Input field */

.questions input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0.7em;
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.questions .current input,
.no-js .questions input {
  opacity: 1;
}

.questions input:focus,
.simform button:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Next question button */

.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 2.15em;
  /* padding-bottom of form plus progress bar height */
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20%);
  transform: translateX(-20%);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.next:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.next::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  line-height: 2;
  speak: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.next.show {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* Progress bar */

.simform .progress {
  width: 0%;
  height: 0.15em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.simform .progress::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  content: '';
}


/* Number indicator */

.simform .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  width: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.4em;
}

.simform .number:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  content: '/';
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.simform .number span {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.simform .number .number-current {
  float: left;
}

.simform .number-next {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.simform.show-next .number-current {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.simform.show-next .number-next {
  -webkit-animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
  animation: moveUpFromDown 0.4s both;
}


/* Error and final message */

.simform .error-message,
.simform .final-message {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.simform .error-message {
  padding: 0.4em 3.5em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.4em;
}

.final-message {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.error-message.show,
.final-message.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.final-message.show {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}


/* Final hiding of form / showing message */

.simform-inner.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}


/* No JS Fallback */

.no-js .simform {
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.no-js .questions li {
  padding: 0 0 2em;
}

.no-js .simform .submit {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.no-js .simform .controls {
  display: none;
}


/* Remove IE clear cross */

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}


/* Adjust form for smaller screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 44.75em) {
  .simform {
    font-size: 1.8em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 33.5625em) {
  .simform {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background: #26C281;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.codrops-header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.codrops-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.codrops-header h1 span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* To Navigation Style */

.codrops-top {
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.69em;
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

section {
  padding: 5em 2em 10em;
  background: #2dcb89;
  text-align: center;
}

section.related {
  padding: 3em 1em 4em;
  background: #465650;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.related>a {
  max-width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
  transition: color 0.3s, border-color 0.3s;
}

.related a:hover {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.related a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.related a:hover img,
.related a:active img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.related a h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.3em;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 44.75em) {
  section {
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
  .codrops-header {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  section.related {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .codrops-icon span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header class="codrops-header">
    <h1>Minimal Form Interface <span>Simplistic, single input view form</span></h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="simform-inner">
        <ol class="questions">
          <li>
            <span><label for="q1">What's your favorite movie?</label></span>
            <input id="q1" name="q1" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q2">Where do you live?</label></span>
            <input id="q2" name="q2" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q3">What time do you got to work?</label></span>
            <input id="q3" name="q3" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q4">How do you like your veggies?</label></span>
            <input id="q4" name="q4" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q5">What book inspires you?</label></span>
            <input id="q5" name="q5" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q6">What's your profession?</label></span>
            <input id="q6" name="q6" type="text" />
          </li>
        </ol>
        <!-- /questions -->
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="next fa fa-long-arrow-right" "></button>
                            <div class="progress "></div>
                            <span class="number ">
                                <span class="number-current "></span>
                                <span class="number-total "></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="error-message "></span>
                        </div><!-- / controls -->
                    </div><!-- /simform-inner -->
                    <span class="final-message "></span>
                </form><!-- /simform -->            
                                     
                                     
            </section>
        
        </div>
    
    <div class="container">
  <header class="codrops-header">
    <h1>Minimal Form Interface <span>Simplistic, single input view form</span></h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="simform-inner">
        <ol class="questions">
          <li>
            <span><label for="q1">What's your favorite movie?</label></span>
            <input id="q1" name="q1" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q2">Where do you live?</label></span>
            <input id="q2" name="q2" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q3">What time do you got to work?</label></span>
            <input id="q3" name="q3" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q4">How do you like your veggies?</label></span>
            <input id="q4" name="q4" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q5">What book inspires you?</label></span>
            <input id="q5" name="q5" type="text" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <span><label for="q6">What's your profession?</label></span>
            <input id="q6" name="q6" type="text" />
          </li>
        </ol>
        <!-- /questions -->
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="next fa fa-long-arrow-right" "></button>
                            <div class="progress "></div>
                            <span class="number ">
                                <span class="number-current "></span>
                                <span class="number-total "></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="error-message "></span>
                        </div><!-- / controls -->
                    </div><!-- /simform-inner -->
                    <span class="final-message "></span>
                </form><!-- /simform -->            
                                     
                                     
            </section>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: Both of your forms have the same ID value, which is invalid for HTML and JavaScript is unable to determine which form you're wanting to use. Make sure both forms have their own unique ID's.

Comment: Maybe you can try with different ID

Comment: Thank you soo much! I just kept playing with the container's id without thinking about the form.